# Insert in SQL Server using odbc

Tags: c++, sql-server, odbc

I am using this code to insert in a table in MS SQL Server: I have this code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714163(v=vs.85).aspx). I have changed this code a little bit to Insert a table in my data base:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <mbstring.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_DATA 100
#define MYSQLSUCCESS(rc) ((rc == SQL_SUCCESS) || (rc == SQL_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) )

class direxec {
   RETCODE rc; // ODBC return code
   HENV henv; // Environment   
   HDBC hdbc; // Connection handle
   HSTMT hstmt; // Statement handle

   unsigned char szData[MAX_DATA]; // Returned data storage
   SDWORD cbData; // Output length of data
   unsigned char chr_ds_name[SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH]; // Data source name

public:
   direxec(); // Constructor
   void sqlconn(); // Allocate env, stat, and conn
   void sqlexec(unsigned char *); // Execute SQL statement
   void sqldisconn(); // Free pointers to env, stat, conn, and disconnect
   void error_out(); // Displays errors
};

// Constructor initializes the string chr_ds_name with the data source name.
// "Northwind" is an ODBC data source (odbcad32.exe) name whose default is the Northwind database
direxec::direxec() {
   _mbscpy_s(chr_ds_name, SQL_MAX_DSN_LENGTH, (const unsigned char *)"TK");
}

// Allocate environment handle and connection handle, connect to data source, and allocate statement handle.
void direxec::sqlconn() {
   SQLAllocEnv(&henv);
   SQLAllocConnect(henv, &hdbc);
   rc = SQLConnect(hdbc, chr_ds_name, SQL_NTS, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);

   // Deallocate handles, display error message, and exit.
   if (!MYSQLSUCCESS(rc)) {
      SQLFreeConnect(henv);
      SQLFreeEnv(henv);
      SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
      if (hstmt)
         error_out();
      exit(-1);
   }

   rc = SQLAllocStmt(hdbc, &hstmt);
}

// Execute SQL command with SQLExecDirect() ODBC API.
void direxec::sqlexec(unsigned char * cmdstr) {
   rc = SQLExecDirect(hstmt, cmdstr, SQL_NTS);
   if (!MYSQLSUCCESS(rc)) {  //Error
      error_out();
      // Deallocate handles and disconnect.
      SQLFreeStmt(hstmt,SQL_DROP);
      SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
      SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
      SQLFreeEnv(henv);
      exit(-1);
   }
   else {
      for ( rc = SQLFetch(hstmt) ; rc == SQL_SUCCESS ; rc=SQLFetch(hstmt) ) {
         SQLGetData(hstmt, 1, SQL_C_CHAR, szData, sizeof(szData), &cbData);
         // In this example, the data is sent to the console; SQLBindCol() could be called to bind 
         // individual rows of data and assign for a rowset.
         printf("%s\n", (const char *)szData);
      }
   }
}

// Free the statement handle, disconnect, free the connection handle, and free the environment handle.
void direxec::sqldisconn() {
   SQLFreeStmt(hstmt,SQL_DROP);
   SQLDisconnect(hdbc);
   SQLFreeConnect(hdbc);
   SQLFreeEnv(henv);
}

// Display error message in a message box that has an OK button.
void direxec::error_out() {
   unsigned char szSQLSTATE[10];
   SDWORD nErr;
   unsigned char msg[SQL_MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH + 1];
   SWORD cbmsg;

   while (SQLError(0, 0, hstmt, szSQLSTATE, &nErr, msg, sizeof(msg), &cbmsg) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
      sprintf_s((char *)szData, sizeof(szData), "Error:\nSQLSTATE=%s, Native error=%ld, msg='%s'", szSQLSTATE, nErr, msg);
      MessageBox(NULL, (const char *)szData, "ODBC Error", MB_OK);
   }
}

int main () {
   direxec x;   // Declare an instance of the direxec object.
   x.sqlconn();   // Allocate handles, and connect.
   x.sqlexec((UCHAR FAR *)"INSERT INTO Infos (Firstname,Lastname,City) VALUES('Babak' , 'Bastan', 'Shiraz')");   // Execute SQL command
   x.sqldisconn();   // Free handles and disconnect
}
```

If I run this code I am getting this error:
[image]

What should I do to solve this problem?
**UPDATE**
at this point of my code block, I get above error:

```
 while (SQLError(0, 0, hstmt, szSQLSTATE, &nErr, msg, sizeof(msg), &cbmsg) == SQL_SUCCESS) {
```

Comment: run your program in a debugger. if you are using visual studio, you can do it in there, for example. some button like "run in debugger".

Comment: After Debugging I get this error. Sorry, I didn't get what you mean exactly

Comment: when you are debugging your own code, and get an error, you should at least know in which line of your code it happens. if not, you may have to compile with debug symbols.

Comment: I have updated my post